# Copying the numeric portion of an address to a new field

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, address

I'm attempting to copy just the numeric portion of a street address into a new table using the Field Calculator in QGIS. The expression I'm trying to use is:

left(  "SITE_ADDR", strpos(  "SITE_ADDR", " " ) -1)

strpos is giving an invalid expression error- column " " not found.

Is there another way to format this expression to actually work?

Comment: What does your site_addr value look like?

Comment: Can you give examples of the 'from' data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your expression should be:

```
left( "SITE_ADDR", strpos( "SITE_ADDR", ' ' ))
```

Note single quotes around string, do not need to minus 1.